# Calculate the limit integral

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I want to compute the following limit
$$ \lim_{x\longrightarrow +\infty}  \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sqrt{\mu+\left(2-\cos (2\pi y) - \cos(2\sqrt{2}\pi y)\right)^2}\;dy$$
where $\mu>0$ is a constant. I don't think about anyway to estimate that.

Edited: One way I think about it is try to use approximation by trigonometric polynomials, then problem will be reduced to the mean of the function, here
$$ H(x,y) = \sqrt{\mu+\left(2-\cos (2\pi x) - \cos(2\pi y)\right)^2}$$
In one dimension we have any $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials. I am not sure we have that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 2$.

Comment: The wanted mean value is the leading coefficient of a Fourier series. If $\mu$ is large, you may employ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and show the almost trivial fact that your mean value is not too far from $\sqrt{\mu}$.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Data fiting gives :$f(\mu )=\sqrt{4.45753\, +1.01349 \mu }$